# Почему после вызова функции записывается значение None

Tags: python, функции, список

Ниже код, реализующий собственный класс Stack и перемещение колец по шпилям (массивам) ханойской башни.
Почему после первого вызова функции move на втором шпиле оказывается None, вместо 'Маленькое кольцо' ? Как это исправить?

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.stack = []
        self.name = name
        self.index = 0

    def push_(self, string_):
        self.index += 1
        self.stack.insert(self.index, string_)

    def pop_(self):
        if self.index <= 0:
            return print('шпиль пуст, нечего удалять!')
        else:
            self.index -= 1
            print('удаляем верхнее кольцо')
            return self.stack.remove(self.stack[self.index])


def move(source, destination):
    element = source.pop_()
    print(element)
    destination.push_(element)

# Называем шпили и присваиваем им класс Stack
first = Stack('Первый шпиль')
second = Stack('Второй шпиль')
third = Stack('Третий шпиль')

# Заполняем шпиль first
big_ring = 'Большое кольцо'
middle_ring = 'Среднее кольцо'
small_ring = 'Маленькое кольцо'
first.push_(big_ring)
first.push_(middle_ring)
first.push_(small_ring)

print('СТАРТОВОЕ СОСТОЯНИЕ')
print(f'Башня: {first.name}, Содержание {first.stack}')
print(f'Башня: {second.name}, Содержание {second.stack}')
print(f'Башня: {third.name}, Содержание {third.stack}')
print('-----------------------------------')

# Решаем задачу
move(first, third)
print(f'Башня: {first.name}, Содержание {first.stack}')
print(f'Башня: {second.name}, Содержание {second.stack}')
print(f'Башня: {third.name}, Содержание {third.stack}')
move(first, second)
move(third, second)
move(first, third)
move(second, first)
move(second, third)
move(first, third)

print(f'Башня: {first.name}, Содержание {first.stack}')
print(f'Башня: {second.name}, Содержание {second.stack}')
print(f'Башня: {third.name}, Содержание {third.stack}')
```

Comment: Метод `remove`, который находится в методе `pop_` Вашего класса, возвращает `None` (а не элемент, как Вы предполагали). Этот `None` Вы принимаете в функции `move`, присваивая ему имя `element`, а затем передаёте в метод `push_`.

Comment: Функции без инструкции return (как и с ней, но без указания аргумента) всегда возвращают — None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.stack = []
        self.name = name
        self.index = 0

    def push_(self, string_):
        self.index += 1
        self.stack.insert(self.index, string_)

    def pop_(self):
        if self.index <= 0:
            return print('шпиль пуст, нечего удалять!')
        else:
            self.index -= 1
            print('удаляем верхнее кольцо', self.stack[self.index])
#            return self.stack.remove(self.stack[self.index])
            stack_remove = self.stack[self.index]                       # +
            self.stack.remove(stack_remove)                             # +
            return stack_remove                                         # +

def move(source, destination):
    element = source.pop_()
    print(element)
    destination.push_(element)

# Называем шпили и присваиваем им класс Stack
first = Stack('Первый шпиль')
second = Stack('Второй шпиль')
third = Stack('Третий шпиль')

# Заполняем шпиль first
big_ring = 'Большое кольцо'
middle_ring = 'Среднее кольцо'
small_ring = 'Маленькое кольцо'
first.push_(big_ring)
first.push_(middle_ring)
first.push_(small_ring)

print('СТАРТОВОЕ СОСТОЯНИЕ')
print(f'Башня: {first.name}, Содержание {first.stack}')
print(f'Башня: {second.name}, Содержание {second.stack}')
print(f'Башня: {third.name}, Содержание {third.stack}')
print('-----------------------------------')

# Решаем задачу
move(first, third)
print(f'Башня: {first.name}, Содержание {first.stack}')
print(f'Башня: {second.name}, Содержание {second.stack}')
print(f'Башня: {third.name}, Содержание {third.stack}')
move(first, second)
print(f'Башня: {first.name}, Содержание {first.stack}')
print(f'Башня: {second.name}, Содержание {second.stack}')
print(f'Башня: {third.name}, Содержание {third.stack}')
move(third, second)
print(f'Башня: {first.name}, Содержание {first.stack}')
print(f'Башня: {second.name}, Содержание {second.stack}')
print(f'Башня: {third.name}, Содержание {third.stack}')
move(first, third)
print(f'Башня: {first.name}, Содержание {first.stack}')
print(f'Башня: {second.name}, Содержание {second.stack}')
print(f'Башня: {third.name}, Содержание {third.stack}')
move(second, first)
print(f'Башня: {first.name}, Содержание {first.stack}')
print(f'Башня: {second.name}, Содержание {second.stack}')
print(f'Башня: {third.name}, Содержание {third.stack}')
move(second, third)
print(f'Башня: {first.name}, Содержание {first.stack}')
print(f'Башня: {second.name}, Содержание {second.stack}')
print(f'Башня: {third.name}, Содержание {third.stack}')
move(first, third)

print(f'Башня: {first.name}, Содержание {first.stack}')
print(f'Башня: {second.name}, Содержание {second.stack}')
print(f'Башня: {third.name}, Содержание {third.stack}')
```